How do you make a mesh with thickness?


In the first image we see 2 meshes: a chocolate shell and an inner candy sponge. The booolean is there to help you see that the chocolate shell has a thickness and the sponge is nested inside the chocolate. In the far right you see that the boolean operation has gotten confused that the outer shell is a mesh.
The second render is what happens when I apply a cell fracture operation to the combined mesh.
Ultimately the goal is to apply a cell fracture operation to this candy, which consists of 2 meshes with 2 shaders. Hoping that the chocolate closest to the sponge will stay with it. Unfortunately the results are difficult to achieve. Please look over the project file and see what you can suggest.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z8lbpd4A9yLwc4YS8c2JRtmvldUWbO3N/view?usp=sharing

Geometry
So... right now, you have 3 meshes inside the object.

Chocolate out
Chocolate in
Sponge

There is absolutely nothing (except your interpretation) that connects choc in and choc out. To the algorithm, it's just 2 whole cubes.
So, if you don't think that could ruin your project, you could make a little hole in the chocolates and connect them together, that way you have two meshes, a hollow chocolate with thickness (recognizable by the algorithm) and the sponge.

The cell fracture does recognize the chocolate properly:

So, geometrically, it works great, but the sad part is: every new face it creates will be created with the first material in the list.

So, if chocolate is the first material (image above, left side), the inside of the sponge will become chocolate
If sponge is the first material (image above, right side), the inside of the chocolate walls will be sponge


Material
Knowing the inside materials will always be the same, you can create a geometry nodes setup that:

gets a material index into an attribute statistics
if sum > 0.1 (mixed materials), set material index to 1


Adding this to all the fractured objects solves the material problem. (there is an option to copy to all selected in the same place where you apply modifiers)
Connection
Unfortunately, I can't imagine an easy solution for choc fragments being connected with their respective sponge fragments if you want that.
But I can imagine a manual work where you manually create tiny connections between the sponge and the chocolate (in a similar way you did the chocolate hole, but now creating a physical mesh link).
The two big downsides are:

Boring manual labor
Disrupts the geonodes for material as it creates parts that are intended to have both materials together


Thanks. This will be pretty useful! The root of the problem may be the cell fracture addon
